# How to display users with same select list value on a custom user profile page

Tags: users

Firstly in my site, using [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). i created a 'Select list field' that allows each user to choose his/her country.

I then created a custom user profile page using views by  following these steps:

1.Create a view and add a "page" display.
2. Use "user/%" as the page path.
3. Add a contextual filter "user uid" and select "provide default value" user ID from URL.

Now i want to add a block to each users profile page that displays all users from the same country as the currently viewed user profile

I have tried adding the "Profile Country" contextual filter and selecting "provide default value" user ID from URL but no results are displayed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're relying on your contextual filter to mean 2 things:

- For the page it has to be the UID.
- For the block it has to be the country select value that corresponds to the UID.

If you're wanting to configure it this way, you'll need your block view to derive the profile country value from a UID. One way you could do this is to use *Provide default value* > **Type**: *PHP Code* options with something like this:

```
if ($user = user_load(arg(1))) {
  $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user);
  return $profile['my_profile_machine_name']->field_my_country_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}
```

The actual code will vary based on your Profile2 configuration.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. One more thing, would you know how i can exclude the currently viewed profile from the block view? (P.S: would you prefer i post this as a separate question?)

Comment: Add another contextual filter; you can add the **User: Uid filter** as you previously did, but use the **More > Exclude** option to negate the effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Create a new view that shows Profiles of the types you defined.
- Select "Create block" instead of "Create page".
- Give it a title, and     select a display, either table, unformatted list of fields or entities, or anything else
- Add a "Contextual filter". Select the **Country field** as contextual filter
- In "When filter value is *not* available" choose "Provide default value"
- Select Type: PHP code

Use a variation of this code, without the php tag

```
global $user;
$profile = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'YOUR_PROFILE_MACHINE_NAME');
$filter = $profile->field_YOUR_COUNTRY_FIELD_NAME[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
return $filter;
```

So, what this code does is: it provides a value to the contextual filter for your profile view, so that only records that match the country code for the currently logged in user will be shown.

NB: you may need to modify the part after [LANGUAGE_NONE] depending on how the value for your country field is store. Alternatively you can use a entity_metadata_wrapper in line 3, as in

```
$w = entity_metadata_wrapper('profile2', $profile); 
$filter = $w->field_YOUR_COUNTRY_FIELD_NAME->value();
```

Additionally you may want to test if the field for Country is empty before everything else.

Don't forget to enable the block in Structure > Blocks so that you can view it.

Good luck.

Comment: There are a few differences between my example and @Shawn Conn's. The main one is that I user global $user to refer to the currently logged in user. His uses the uid provided in the URL. Re-reading your post I now realize that you want to show same country for the CURRENTLY VIEWED profile. Then his code is the one to use.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Yes the code provided by @shawn solves the issue.